# Don't save the hidden events calendar fields

Tags: calendar, dropdown, events, sharepoint-fields

I hide some fields dynamically on my calendar event (SharePoint 2013) with jquery following a dropdown choice. When I create an event, it saves the default value of each hidden field but I don't want to save them because I generate reports with an another soft, so I don't want to show fields which have no relationship with the event.
Do you know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the fields are hidden, SharePoint still reads them and saves them (as you've experienced). You can use jQuery to change the values of the hidden fields to be blank or whatever, so it'll save an empty value.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to modify the value when I click to the save button. I can modify the value like this :
$("input[title$=Revendeur]").val("test");
But when I try to modify the value in the click function of the save button, it doesn't success, it keeps the old value :
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
   $("input[title$=Revendeur]").val("");
});

Answer (score 0):

Go to list content type and make them as hidden those are not required.
Hidden the fields in list content type make them not to appear on newform page of list.
Then create a view which can contain only those fields whom you want to display.